# Why is my directive controller breaking when I remove jQuery

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I had jQuery as a dependency but was not using it. After I removed it one of my methods in my directive controller has stops working.

I have the following bower.json

bower.json file:

```
{
  "name": "Mendelhealth",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Front end application code.",
  "authors": [
    "Aaron Balthaser"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "susy": "^2.2.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.5.3",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.2.18",
    "angular-animate": "^1.5.3",
    "angular-material": "master",
    "angular-material-icons": "^0.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.0.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.5.7"
  },
  "overrides": {}
}
```

The this.filter found in my directive controller is breaking when I remove jQuery reference. This is really baffling to me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Directive:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('timeline')
    .directive('timeline', function() {

      function link() {

      }

      return {
        link: link,
        controller: 'TimelineCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'timeline',
        templateUrl: 'app/modules/timeline/timeline.html'
      };
    });
}());
```

Directive Controller:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('timeline')
    .controller('TimelineCtrl',
        ['$rootScope', '$http', 'API_URL', 'timelineData',
            function($rootScope, $http, API_URL, timelineData) {

      var that = this;
      this.datum = [];

      timelineData.async().then(function(data) {
        that.datum = data;
        that.datum.sort(function(dateA, dateB) {
          return new Date(dateB.date) - new Date(dateA.date);
        });
      });

      this.filter = function(category) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('filter', category);
      };

      this.removeFilter = function() {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('removefilter', '');
      };
    }]);
}());
```

Directive Template:

```
<div class="vertical-padding">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav id="timeline-navigtaion">
      <ul>
        <li
            class="timeline-navigtaion-item"
            ng-click="removeFilter()">All
        </li>
        <li
            class="timeline-navigtaion-item"
            ng-click="timeline.filter('imaging')">Imaging
        </li>
        <li
            class="timeline-navigtaion-item"
            ng-click="timeline.filter('medications')">Medications
        </li>
        <li
            class="timeline-navigtaion-item"
            ng-click="timeline.filter('problems')">Problems
        </li>
        <li
            class="timeline-navigtaion-item"
            ng-click="timeline.filter('procedures')">Procedures
        </li>
        <li
            class="timeline-navigtaion-item"
            ng-click="timeline.filter('genetics')">Genetics
        </li>
        <li
            class="timeline-navigtaion-item"
            ng-click="timeline.filter('pathology')">Pathology
        </li>
        <li
            class="timeline-navigtaion-item"
            ng-click="timeline.filter('notes')">Notes
        </li>
        <li
            class="timeline-navigtaion-item"
            ng-click="timeline.filter('labs')">Labs
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <section id="timeline" class="timeline-container">
      <div timeline-item class="timeline-block"
          datum="timeline.datum[$index]"
          ng-repeat="item in timeline.datum">
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you have `jQuery` dependency in bower.json file

Comment: Im sorry I updated my question. I do not understand why the method in my directive controller is breaking after I remove jQuery from the html entry point of my app.

Comment: How is this related to Angular Material?

Comment: You should post the error that you're getting...

Comment: I added Angular Material because I am using it and on the off chance it may have been relevant to know. I have no idea why the method is breaking so I cannot be sure what information is necessary.

Comment: There is no error to post. The filter just stops working.

Comment: For some reason the method is no longer being called when clicking on the filter items.

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle or plunker?

Comment: Are you sure the function is not being called? That function is using `$broadcast` ... another possibility is that the function is being called, but the thing that is listening for the `$broadcast` is not receiving the events.

Comment: Yeah Im sure it wasn't being called. Its really weird. All I did was delete the jquery ref and it stopped working. I fixed it by taking the markup in the directive template and placing it directly in the dashboard view and used ng-controller in the markup and everything worked again. I honestly do not understand what was the issue.

Comment: So just for clarification I had the directive in another view for the dashboard like so:

<timeline></timeline>

I basically removed the directive and added the above template markup directly in that view getting rid of the directive and I declared the above controller like so:

<div class="vertical-padding" ng-controller="TimelineCtrl">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <nav id="timeline-navigation">
code ...

For some reason everything worked again.